# console.log or a function to show the result

Tags: javascript, alert, document.write, console.log

I have a simple problem:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var numero= Number(prompt("Inserisci un numero e sarà moltiplicato per 2^10!" , "Inserisci qui il numero"));
            var counter= 0; 

                while (counter < 10)
                    { result = result * 2; counter = counter + 1;
                    }
                document.write(numero);
```

This is my code and I want to understand why I couldn't see the result. I also tried to use the function console.log and alert, but it doesn't work. 
Can you also explain me the main difference between the function console.log, document.write and alert? 
Thanks you to everyone.

Comment: `console.log` logs in the browser's console. `document.write` does [nasty things](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#document.write%28%29). `alert` pauses script execution and shows an alert.

Comment: The difference between "console.log, document.write and alert" is *literally everything*. They are completely different functions that do completely different things. You're asking us to tell you the difference between a giraffe and a space ship.

Answer (score 1):

The very first thing you do is `result = result * 2;`, however you never initialize `result`. You need to initialize it before you attempt to access it or you'll raise something like the following:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: result is not defined

Answer (score 0):

- **console.log**: logs at the browser console (press F12 to see it)
- **document.write**: writes at page ifself (don't use it)
- **alert**: shows a browser alert box (avoid it)

if you need to debug code, avoid all; use the browser debugger (F12 > sources or F12 > debugger).

Comment: F12 opens devtools on IE. To open the console on Firefox, it's Ctrl+Shift+K for the web console and Ctrl+Shift+J for the browser console. On Chrome, it's Ctrl+Shift+J.